# Points $A,B,C$ are given, find a line and a point such that distance of $A,B,C$ from that line is equal to distance of $A,B,C$ from that point.

Tags: geometry, locus

In the name of God
Suppose points $A(1,2)$ and $B(2,5) , C(3,10)$ are given. Find equation of line $l$ and point $F$ such that $AH = AF , BH' = BF , CH'' = CF$, where $AH, BH' $and$ CH''$ are perpendicular lines to line $l$.
I first tried to solve this by solving system of equation. Suppose equation of line $l$ is equal to  $y = mx+b$. and point $O$ is equal to $(x,y)$.  
$m,b,x,y$ are unknown here, but we have only $3$ equalities (one for each point).

It is impossible to solve a system of equation with $4$ unknown variables and $3$ equalities. 
I know the correct way of solving this question. There is only one parabola crossing $3$ points and we can find the equation of that parabola. By calculating the focus and the directrix of that parabola, we can find the answer.
But my question is why my method isn't working? How is it possible for a system of equation with $4$ unknown variables and $3$ equalities to have a unique answer?

Comment: What do you use as point $O$? Is it on the line?

Comment: NO. Point O is located somewhere in coordinate system and we should calculate its coordinates. e.g. : for A(1,2) , B(2,5) , C(3,10), point O is (0,1.25) and equation of line l is : y = 0.75 . ( m=0 , b=0.75 ,x= 0, y=1.25)

Comment: Pick an arbritrary point $F$ other than $A, B, C$. Pick an arbitrary line running through $A$ but not $F. B$ or $C$. Draw the parallel lines through $B$ and $C$. If either of those lines runs though $F$ or both of $B$ and $C$, go back an pick a different line through $A$. By the fourth try, you have to get one that succeeds. Now pick one of the two points on the line through $A$ that are a distance $|AF|$ from $A$ and call it $H$. Do the same thing for the lines through $B$ and $C$ to get $H'$, $H''$. Choose $l$ to be any perpendicular to $AH$.

Comment: My point is, you are acting like this is some completely specified problem with a single solution, but the conditions you've given fall far short of that. There are uncountably many points $F$ and lines $l$ fitting the conditions you've listed, because the equations $AH = AF, BH' = BF. CH'' = CF$ don't actually add any requirements to the system, as the only other requirements on $H, H', H''$ are that they lie somewhere on the perpendiculars to $l$ through $A,B,C$ respectively. Are you missing some additional conditions?

Comment: There should be a certain condition of A B C to have such solution.

Comment: Hi.You're right. I guess this issue would be solved if I used numbers instead variables. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinite solutions to this problem.  Each solution is a parabola.

To find these solutions, we parameterize them by the direction of the axis of the parabola.

Define a new coordinate frame $O x' y'$ such that

$ (x, y) = R (x' , y') $

where

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta && - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta && \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} $

We are given the points $A,B,C$ with coordinates defined in the $Oxy$ frame, from which we can derive their coordinates in the $Ox'y'$ as follows

$ A' = R^T A $

$B' = R^T B $

$C' = R^T C $

Now the parabola has the equation

$ y' = a x'^2 + b x' + c $

Substituting $A', B', C'$ gives a linear system of three equations in the unknowns $a,b,c$

Upon solving the system, we put the parabola in vertex format

$ y' = a (x' - x'_0)^2 + y'_0 $

where $x_0 = \dfrac{-b}{2a}$ , and $y'_0 = c - \dfrac{b^2}{4a} $

Define the parabola parameter $p = \dfrac{1}{4a}$

Then with respect to the frame $O'x'y'$ the focus of the parabola is

$ F' = (x'_0 , y'_0 + p ) $

And the directrix is

$ y' = y'_0 - p $

At the final step, we have to transform these back to the world frame, so that

$ F = R F' $

and

$ [0, 1] R^T (x, y) = y'_0 - p $

This equation can be re-written as follows

$ - \sin \theta \ x + \cos \theta y = y'_0 - p $

This completes the specification of the required point $F$ and the line $\ell$ as functions of the angle $\theta$.

Here are some parabolas with different orientation for the three given points in the problem.

[image]

Comment: In the name of Allah. I really appreciate your answer. But as a high schooler I have to say this is beyond my knowledge. What do you mean by 'There are infinite solutions to this '? You mean there are infinite pairs of 'point F' and 'line l' ? but that does not make sense to me because there is only one parabola crossing A,B,C which is $ y=x^2+ 1$.

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what I mean.  There are infinite pairs of 'point F' and 'line L' that will satisfy the requirements of the problem (namely, that the distance to $F$ is equal to the perpendicular distance to $L$).  That is because, the parabola doesn't have to be oriented with its axis parallel to the $Y$-axis, it can be along any direction.  And this is why I used the rotation matrix $R$.  Check the updated solution with the graph of some of these possible parabolas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for updating answer! I first thought that there is only one parabola because$ y = ax^2 + bx + c$ is general form of parabolas and we can find values of a,b,c by having three point and replacing y and x and solving system. But I now realize rotated parabolas can have different equations. eg: $y= \pm \sqrt{x}$

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help.